# Repository layer method return type

Tags: .net, unit-testing

```
public void SaveStatus(Status newStatus);
```

The above method saves some new status to the DB. Should it return something like a boolean flag to indicate success or failure of the save operation.

While writing a unit test, I got a question on what I assert, whether `SaveStatus()` is successful or not. If there are no exceptions thrown, it can be considered successful in case of unit tests.

What is the best practice around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**

The method´s name let us known clearly its contract: it has to save the status. When a method, for any reason cannot do what it has to do, it has to throw an exception, that´s the way OOP works. If you return an error code or flag you will end having the following in all the callers:

```
if(xxx.SaveStatus(newStatus)){
   // do something
}
else
{
   // and here.. what? return another boolean???? Ignore it???? ummmm
}
```

If it fails, you will get an exception and that is enough.

In your UT you have to assert the new status was saved, to do that you have to mock your database access using a Repository for example or whatever you are using.

Comment: You could throw in a comment about CQS to put the final nail in. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, this doesn't make sense. It is invalid to return a value from a function
returning void.you can return the boolean value though. getting desired output from function you called is nothing but its success.

Answer (score 1):

No, it should not. This would be a clear vioation of [Command Query Separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation). A method should either return something **OR** mutate some state, never both.

Since you're using .NET, you should leverage exceptions to indicate failure.

Answer (score 1):

Throw an exception to indicate failure.  This allows you to include failure details that application logic can use to decide how to handle the failure.  To @Hexxagonal's point, this can be a bad technique if the code fails a lot, but if your Repository layer fails a lot, performance will not be your biggest concern.

To unit test, mock the storage mechanism (database?) and verify calls on the mock.  I recommend [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about success, then yes you can return a boolean indicating success/failure.  The other likely option would be to throw an exception.  I prefer to use booleans as return values instead of throwing exceptions. If exceptions do occur within that method, I will take care of them inside of the `SaveStatus` method and return a false.

The reason I don't tend to throw exceptions in this case is because it can negatively impact the performance of your application.  Microsoft standards states that "[for code that routinely fails, you can use design patterns to minimize performance issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229009%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)".

Comment: I would disagree with your second point, I wouldn't consider a DB failure as a "*routine*" failure. You shouldn't *expect* your DB to fail therefore an exception is more appropriate.